# How to replicate the Hibernate's @Where functionality in Spring JPARepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

One of our entities is defined using the @Where annotation to handle "soft-deletes".

```
@Entity
@Where(clause="user_type_cd != 'X'")
public class User {
...
```

Now, we are realizing that at times, we still want to find such entities.  Unfortunately, the @Where annotation is working as designed and so the finders we have defined in JPARepository do not work to find deleted Users.

For example,

```
@Repository("userRepo")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByLoginId(String login);
}
```

If the user has been deleted, then the findByLoginIs() method will not return a user if user_type_cd equals to 'X'.

However, at times, we still want to find such a user, so I was thinking of moving the

```
@Where(clause="user_type_cd != 'X'")
```

annotation from the entity into the repository.  This way, I don't have to update all the methods in the repository and it would automatically add this criterium to all the finders.  Then, I can create another repository which will find ALL the Users without regard to soft deletes.

However, I am not able to figure out the exact method that I can use to make all of the finders automatically append the

```
clause="user_type_cd != 'X'"
```

criteria to all methods of the repository without me having to explicitly write a custom @Query("... and user_type_cd != 'X'") for each finder method.

So, in short, I am looking for all the auto-generated findBy and such methods to append the user_type_cd != 'X' to each find that is generated.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without resorting to custom @Query annotation?

Comment: FWIW `@Where` is nothing to do with JPA API. Perhaps you mean to tag this as Hibernate

Comment: Well, I am looking to replicate the behavior of the @Where using Spring Data JPA Repository.  In other words, my Repository has quite a bit of finder methods in it, and I want them all to append this chunk of criteria to every finder query that they do.  So in my mind, it's less of a hibernate specific thing and more of how do I get this done with Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is one of either:

1. [Spring data jpa specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html), or
2. [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html)

There's a wealth of information with a simple google search on either. Here's a useful [spring.io blog](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) with details on both, and how to use them with a JpaRepository.

Comment: Can you take the info from those links and show us how it applies to the OP's question?